# Group work + Database Dependant CMS + Version control

Tags: mysql, database, version-control

We're running into a problem where I work at, since we're getting bigger and more of us are working on the same project simultaneously. We use version control (git) for the code, so no problem on this side. (each of us has its own local site, we have a dev site online, and the final production one online).

But when it comes to database, we're running into a wall. We use a CMS (for e-shops) heavily dependent on database. Whenever we install a module, it writes into 3 or 4 tables with auto increment IDs, but this module can also creates files, create tables... and so on.
So when we just commit/push, then when someone pull, he doesn't have the "up to date" database, and it can cause crashes or weird side effect bugs.

Plus, we can't "simply" copy/paste all the database from local to local and/or preprod to local because domain name, paths, and other configurations are in the database too. So we'd need a clever tool...

The perfect world would be that I add a new functionality on my computer, then I push it on git, and **whoever pull afterwards can get the relevant *(with "ignore" on some parts ?)* database changes merging with his own localhost**. (at the moment, we have to redo the same manipulations on every single computer/environment, if I add a functionnality on my computer and configure it, I have to do the same on preprod, but it can break other people localhost).

Thanks for your lights.

Comment: "because domain name, paths, and other configurations are in the database too." That seems to be a bad idea because you will get in same troubles when you try to move to another host. However - why don't you just "ignore" the configuration tables in git?

Comment: We're using a CMS and we didn't make the choice of storing these datas in the database.
Plus, the configuration table is also where modules configurations are, so if we ignore it, we might have malfunctions from one env to another :(

Answer (score 0):

We were running into similar issues in a project I ran a few years ago. We used Redgate's products for managing several SQLServer databases. They have other databases as well.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/

The product allows developers to be aware of database differences, handles both schema and data separately, and, if memory serves, even offers migration scripts to update schema and transform the data in the database. The only downside is that its merge capability is limited. But being aware of others' changes is really most of the battle.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it :)